# Evaluating Determinants by Row Reduction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

My problem:

> Suppose $$
> \begin{vmatrix}a & b& c \\ d & e & f \\ g& h & i\end{vmatrix} = 8.
> $$
>   Then find the value of $$
> \begin{vmatrix} (g+2a) & (h+2b)& (i+2c) \\ 3a & 3b & 3c \\ 2d& 2e & 2f\end{vmatrix}.
> $$

I believe the final answer is $-48$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please [edit] your question to include your thoughts and previous attempts on this problem. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It would help if you'd share how you got to $-48$.

Comment: The second row in the original question was $3a,3b,3c$.

Comment: You can take out the factors $3$ and $2$ from the last two rows as factors to the determinant. Then you can subtract the second row twice from the first row. This wouldn't change the determinant. Finally you can switch the positions of rows to get the second row to the top and the first row all the way down to the bottom. Each time two rows are switched you change the determinant's sign.

Comment: To get that answer, you must have done some work, try to include them.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Clearly false, since they already got an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate having to open a link when it is not **that** difficult to type the problem here!
The problem is 
"Given that $\left|\begin{array}{ccc}a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i\end{array}\right|= 8$

Find the value of $\left|\begin{array}{ccc}(g+ 2a) & (h+ 2b) & (i+ 2c) \\ 3a & 3b & 3c \\ 2d & 2c & 2f\end{array}\right|$."

There are three kinds of "row operations":
1) Multiply a row by a number.  This multiplies the determinant by the number.
2) Swap two rows.  This multiplies the determinant by -1.
3) Add a multiple of one row to another.  This does not change the determinant.

Starting from $\left|\begin{array}{ccc}a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i\end{array}\right|$, multiply the first row by 2 to get $\left|\begin{array}{ccc}2a & 2b & 2c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i\end{array}\right|= 2(8)= 16$.

Add the third row to the first row of that to get $\left|\begin{array}{ccc}g+ 2a & h+ 2b & i+ 2c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i\end{array}\right|= 16$.

Multiply the second row of that by 3 to get $\left|\begin{array}{ccc}g+ 2a & h+ 2b & i+ 2c \\ 3d & 3e & 3f \\ g & h & i\end{array}\right|= 3(16)= 48$.

Finally, multiply the third row of that by 2 to get $\left|\begin{array}{ccc}g+ 2a & h+ 2b & i+ 2c \\ 3d & 3e & 3f \\ 2g & 2h & 2i\end{array}\right|= 2(48)= 96$.

Comment: Look at the second and third rows.

Comment: To put it more directly, you’ve computed the wrong determinant.

Comment: Yes, I see that now.  Thank you.

Comment: My apologies im still getting used to this site and when i tried typing it out , it came out looking horrible! about your 2nd step , adding the third row to the 1st row , does that not affect the out come in anyway? (also apologies for the super late reply , again really new)